# Can I use JQuery MOBILE as the codebase for my simple Facebook App?

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I have a running JQueryMobile App that I"m developing with PhoneGap for Android/IPhone, and it's going well.  However, I'd like to use the same JQueryMobile codebase to extend the application to Facebook.  When my FB app is inside of the Facebook IFRAME, it renders, but when I click my first jquerymobile "#abcdef" link, it either crashed my Chrome broswer altogether, or it navigates "back 2x" in the browser, or it pops me out to my app page, some strange behavior.  Does anyone have any suggestions on getting a jquerymobile codebase to work on the web as an embedded Facebook App?  Are there some settings that will allow my mobile app to work more like a web app in certain contexts?  Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook iFrame Canvas apps are quirky. The facebook parent frame will post to your iframe in addition to other things that seem very odd to me (MS web background).

Theoretically you could leave the markup the same, but not initialize jQuery Mobile for your facebook app, but that will get messy. I'd recommend a separate set of views (html pages) for your facebook canvas.